# T-SQL Full outer join on two subqueries or arbitrary static values?

Tags: sql-server, join

I'm trying to basically combine the columns from two outputs into one row.

Here's one example:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'Today' AS Txt) t1
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT GETDATE() AS D) t2)
-- desired result is one row with a 'Txt' column with value 'Today' and a 'D' column with the result of the GETDATE function
```

And another:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM dbo.myTableFunc()) t1 -- returns 5 rows
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM dbo.myOtherTableFunc())) t2 -- also returns 5 rows
```

The thing I cannot figure out how to do is to do the "outer join" on the two subqueries. In the first example, I'm basically trying to combine the result of two scalars into a single row result. In the second I'm trying to take two tables, each with five rows, and combine their columns, without any relationship between the data in the two tables.

I'm trying to do the above in a UDF and also in a view, so anything that involves creating temporary tables will not work.

In both of the above cases I get syntax errors around the closing ) signs in the outer join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing the join conditions.  in the first example, your join condition is "always", or 1 = 1:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'Today' AS Txt) t1
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT GETDATE() AS D) t2) t2 on 1=1
```

In the second example you don't want any relationship between the rows in each data set - well, if you want to join them then there needs to be SOME relationship, even if it's spurious.  Using a row number like this would work (assumes you have a unique column called `Id` in both tables):

```
select * from (
    select row_number() over (order by Id asc) rn, * from dbo.myTableFunc()
) t1
full join (
    select row_number() over (order by Id asc) rn, * from dbo.myOtherTableFunc()
) t2 on t1.rn=t2.rn
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! Didn't know you could use 1=1 as the join condition.